# Make label multiline

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know the easy solution would be to make the label a textbox with multiline but this does not solve the problem since I want to render anchor tags inside the text value. For example:

```
 <asp:Label ID='myLabel' runat="server" Text=" This is my label etc... go 
here  <a href='Destn.aspx'>Here</a> to update" />
```

This can't be done by using a textbox since a textbox will not display the anchor tag as a link instead it will display as plain text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<asp:Label 
    ID='myLabel' 
    runat="server"  
    style="word-wrap:break-word;" 
    Width="140px" 
    Text=" This is my label etc... go here <a href='Destn.aspx'>Here</a> to update" />
```

Add width property and provide any appropriate value whatever you want and add one css style which will wrap the word

Answer (score 7):

Use `<br/>` in your TEXT to create new row in label text.

```
<asp:Label ID='myLabel' 
       runat="server" 
       Text=" This is my label etc... go <br /> here  
       <a href='Destn.aspx'>Here</a> to update" />
```

See: [`<br>` - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

> The HTML `<br>` Element (or HTML Line Break Element) produces a line
>   break in text (carriage-return).

Comment: I don't want to use a break because I need it to be more dynamic.The content could be more than 50 lines

Comment: @Jake, define a width then, it will wrap the text by default and if the text is more than the width then it will move on to the next line.

Comment: You can simply use HTML Span Element, it will be faster the label, you can use it by making it runat="sever"

Answer (score 0):

Select the dropdown next to the label.  Then Press Ctrl + Enter key for Line - break

**Edit**

It work only when page open in Design Mode