# How to use HTML code in label text get via resoucekey

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, label

I'm getting text of label via `meta:resourcekey`:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" SkinID="gold"
      meta:resourcekey="notiEmailTextBoxResource1"></asp:Label>
```

I want to use html code in this text.

I tried:

> "Email `<br/>`(Put a semicolon ';' character, between e-mail addresses)"
>
> "Email `/n`(Put a semicolon ';' character, between e-mail addresses)"
>
> "Email `&lt;br /&gt;` (Put a semicolon ';' character, between e-mail addresses)"

but none of them worked.

**I don't want to do this process in a .cs file.**

Comment: Just formatting. I think the question is fairly clear already. Added specific tag.

Comment: Guys I need an answer, not a beautiful looking question!

Comment: Do the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16662369/256431) help when specifying the text via resourcekey?